# How to sort slices in a MicroStrategy pie chart?

Tags: charts, pie-chart, microstrategy

I have a field category and a field sub category in my data.
I want to display the sub categories in a pie chart but coloring and sorting them by categories.

I'm currently at this point :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tuas.png)

but I need to order the sub categories by categories, all red then all yellow then all green etc

How can I manage to do that?